# Non zero positive road

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

We Call non zero positive road every sequence  $(u_0,…,u_n)$ of {-1,1}$^{n+1}$ such as : $\\$

i) for all k ∈{0,…,n},$ \sum_{i=0}^{k} u_{i} ≥ 0 $ $\\$

ii)$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} u_i = 0$ $\\$

how many nonzero positive road of taille n existe?

I have made a try

if we note them $r_{n}$ : 
$r_{2n} = n^2 $ and $ r_{2n+1}= 0$
$\textbf{ this problem is from Polytechnique X Paris oral Exam 2019}$

Comment: Do you know Catalan numbers?

Comment: Hint: [Catalan numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: Not really, but I will look for them , thank you